# How to tell if Facebook app is on a page?

Tags: facebook, web-scraping

The approach I've been using initially was:

```
http_head('http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test/' . $input['fb_page_id'] . '?sk=app_' . $input['fb_id']), 'HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently')
```

The problem with this approach is:

1. If the page doesn't exist at all, Facebook will return `200` header, rather than `404` (eg. `http://www.facebook.com/pages/Test/DominosPizza?sk=app_311706258843058`).
2. If page has a username, this request will return response `301` response.

I am building a script that occasionally goes through all instances of `<div data-page="130414917005937" data-app="299770086775725"></div>` in my portfolio. Then checks if the app is still on the page. If the app is on the page, it will provide a link, otherwise leave the tag as it was.

**I am looking for a solution that does not require access token.**

Comment: @phwd, Random string since I don't know the actual title of the page. As far as I know, it is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless Facebook changes their URL scheme, this works.

Note, that this method issues a `HEAD` request, rather than `GET`. Therefore, no content is downloaded. For further explanation how/why this works refer to http://anuary.com/47/keeping-facebook-portfolio-up-to-date.

Take a note that if Page privacy settings restrict unauthenticated users, you need to fake user authentication in order for this to work.

```php
$fn_is_app_on_page  = function($page_id, $app_id)
{
    $ch         = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch,
    [
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT       => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_0) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11',
        CURLOPT_URL             => 'https://www.facebook.com/pages/anuary/' . $page_id . '?sk=app_' . $app_id,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION  => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HEADER          => FALSE,
        CURLOPT_NOBODY          => TRUE
    ]);

    $response   = curl_exec($ch);

    $info       = curl_getinfo($ch);

    curl_close($ch);

    if($info['http_code'] == '404')
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    if(strpos($info['url'], (string) $app_id) !== FALSE)
    {
        return TRUE;
    }

    return FALSE;
};

$fn_is_app_on_page(130414917005937, 299770086775725); // TRUE
$fn_is_app_on_page(1, 299770086775725); // FALSE
$fn_is_app_on_page(130414917005937, 1); // FALSE
```

Comment: This method is no longer reliable. Facebook will redirect the suspicious client to the main page.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the official way to find out if a Facebook page has the app installed on it.

See http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

> **Testing App Installs**
>
> You can test if a specific app is installed on a page profile tab by
>   issuing an HTTP GET to `PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID`.
>
> This request will work for any APP_ID and return the above fields is
>   the app is installed on the page. If the app is not installed on the
>   page, this request will return an empty data[] array.
>
> You can also issue this same query with an app access token. In this
>   case, you can query any PAGE_ID, and the above fields will be returned
>   if your app is installed on the specified page. An empty data[] array
>   is returned as usual if the app is not installed on the specified
>   page.

So it's a simple HTTP GET to `http://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/tabs/APP_ID`

Comment: The only problem with this is approach is that it requires access token.

Comment: It's not a problem, it's a __requirement__.

Comment: I didn't ask how to get this done when access token is available (as clearly stated in the comments). Thus, your solution is irrelevant.

Comment: If it's so important to your question, then you should put it in the question itself.  :(

Comment: @Guy if you have an app, you have an app access token, so why not use it?

Comment: @bool.dev I don't always have the access token.

Comment: +1, i don't know why there's still a bounty here, this is the only supported way to check for the presence of a page tab via the API - scraping the site manually has its own set of problems but could work too

Comment: @igy the question reads quite clearly - [how to achieve this] without access token. It isn't a sensitive information in any way. It would be nice if it was accessible through API, though it isn't. There I am looking for an alternative workaround.

Answer (score 2):

You can examine the http response of the page you are requesting and search for the string `pagelet_app_APPID` (where APPID is the actual application id)

this addresses issue 1 because this string will not exist on the page if the page requested is not actually the tab application.

in response to issue 2, in the event of a 301, follow the redirect and and search the response of the redirected page for this string.

**Edited 10/29/12**

I just looked into this issue a little further.  The reason that the first page is not available to anonymous users.  This is due to some permissions restrictions set by the page admin.  It is because of these restrictions that facebook is requiring a user to authenticate before the page is seen.  When you use cURL, facebook sees this request as an anonymous user and is redirecting the request to the login page.  The second app does not have this issue.

To resolve this, i would suggest inspecting your facebook cookies after you log in using your browser and send those as part of the cURL request.

Comment: If you see my answer, this unfortunately does't work because Facebook may redirect you as well to http://facebook.com/ with 301 even when the app is on the page.

Comment: This is fine because pagelet_app_APPID will not be on the page if you are redirected to Facebook.com.  As long as you check the terminating page's HTML response for that string, you can be sure that the page you found has the app.

Comment: Do you have an example of where a page has the app and the redirection still occurs?

Comment: I've hacked together this example, http://dev.anuary.com/tmp/test.php (https://gist.github.com/52abcf80d6151c9e311d). The 327278224034865 app is obviously on the 109624395762187, though user is redircted to http://facebook.com/.

Comment: Using the page and app ids you provided, i did the following: https://www.facebook.com/pages/test/109624395762187?sk=app_327278224034865 redirects to https://www.facebook.com/Nurofen?sk=app_327278224034865 and `pagelet_app_327278224034865` is located in the html of that page.  Also, 

https://www.facebook.com/pages/test/332170730191943?sk=app_369986216409258 redirects to https://www.facebook.com/stitchesthemovie?sk=app_369986216409258 and `pagelet_app_369986216409258` exists in the html of the page

Comment: Absolutely, I can reproduce the same behaviour using browser. However, if you were using PHP cURL http://facebook.com/pages/test/109624395762187?sk=app_327278224034865 would redirect you to http://facebook.com/. Which is essentially why I started the bounty.

Comment: i just edited my answer to address this.  hopefully that helps.

Answer (score -4):

The following code will help you find out if the app is loaded through a Facebook Page.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var isInIFrame = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? true : false;
    if (isInIFrame == true){
        //enter your code here
    }

});

</script>
```

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with the question.